# How to handle coordinated events in FRP

Tags: functional-programming, reactive-programming

With functional reactive programming, is there a common technique for handling events in different streams that must be coordinated?

E.g. suppose you have streams A, B, C that are related like A -> B, B -> C, and A -> C (i.e. B depends on A, C depends on A and B). If A emits an event, for some period C is holding the latest A, but old B (which is derived from the old A), which is an inconsistent state for stream C.

There are various solutions that require deep knowledge of whole FRP stream graph, e.g. if C knows all the relationships between its dependencies, it will know B depends on A, and can wait for both A and B before emitting. This seems complex and expensive.

Comment: I don't quite understand the situation. Maybe you could give a specific example (or code) that demonstrates the issue?